# elastic beanstalk: create rails env with postgres RDS from beginning?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have not been able to successfully launch my postgres rails app on elastic beanstalk.

I was able to create a fresh app, with sqlite3, then add postgres RDS, then migrate the app to use pg instead of sqlite3.

But i think if the app is a postgres app, then it will never boot, and never be in a stable state which allows for adding a postgres database.

How can i add steps to the `eb create` to include a postgres database with proper config for a rails application.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that calling `eb create --database --database.engine postgres` might accomplish what you want; see [this page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-create.html) for details. (You'd probably also need to specify the other `--database.` parameters as well.)

However, I would strongly recommend that you do **not** do this, as it will tie your EB instance and RDS instance together. If you ever terminate your instance, your database (and all its contents and automatic backups) will be deleted.

Instead, I would recommend that you create your PostgreSQL RDS instance separately and then associate it to your EB instance by setting the following configuration variables:

- RDS_HOSTNAME=.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
- RDS_DB_NAME=ebdb
- RDS_PASSWORD=
- RDS_USERNAME=
- RDS_PORT=5432